# Keeping a counter immutably in scala?

Tags: scala

My professor has a rule that if we use any mutation whatsoever, we get a 0 on the assignment. This means I cannot keep a simple counter. Is there some way to be able to keep a counter immutably?

I should note that the assignment is not "create an immutable counter in scala", it is somewhat more involved, this is just a hiccup I've come across.

Comment: Recursion and / or creating a copy of the counter withe the value increased / decreased as needed.

Comment: Seems like your prof wanna shape your mindset into FP. Do you have a more detailed requirements for your case?

Comment: @swiftmango I agree that he wants us to get into this mindset. The use case is just that I'm reading a file from disk and want to count the lines (file is large so .length is not an option). The actual assignment is to do with processing the files contents.

Comment: @Aserian you need to use `foldLeft` to do the processing and the count.

Comment: I see, is there any reason foldleft vs regular fold?

Comment: @Aserian what do you mean with regular fold? `foldLeft` is the regular fold, the method called `fold` is almost useless.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez was what I needed,

```
val lineCount = longFileIterator.foldLeft(0)((acc, line) => {
  //process line
  acc + 1
})
```